# Ways that a mom ask her child to wear properly in cold weather

Tags: word-request, sentence-usage

It's difficult for me to find the correct words to ask my young brother that told me that he's cold. I want to ask him about the quality of his dressing, I mean if he weared properly before he left home.

I'm looking for the ways that a native English parent usually tell or ask his children how to dress in a cold weather. Let's imagine a mom  which her son calls her and tells her that he's cold, then she'll be interested to know about the quality of her son cloths, what usually the kind of the question will be?

> Did you dress / wear  warm cloths?
>
> Are you dressed  / weared properly and **warmly**?

Answer (score 1):

Of your examples, the one that would most likely be used is:

> Did you wear warm clothes?

You'll often hear this said a lot more casually:

> Have you got warm clothes on?
>
> Did you have warm clothes on?

You'll also often hear reference to a specific garment:

> Did you have a warm coat on?

Answer (score 1):

You could ask specific questions:

> Are you wearing a coat?
>
> Did you dress warmly?

Or you could ask them for information:

> What are you wearing?

A common, informal way to ask if they are dressed warmly is:

> Are you bundled up?